# Do Google Sheets logical operators short circuit?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Basically the title. Making a big Analytics based spreadsheet that tests for a lot of date conditions. I would like to know if the AND operator supports short-circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

"short-circuit evaluation" is basically nesting of `IF` functions:

```
=IF(A1=1, TRUE,
 IF(A1=2, TRUE))
```

for multi-criteria it would be:

```
=IF(AND(A1=1, B1=1), TRUE,
 IF(AND(A1=2, B1=2), TRUE))
```

when it comes to arrays/ranges it will be like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A1:A=1) * (B1:B=1), TRUE,
              IF((A1:A=2) * (B1:B=2), TRUE)))
```

Comment: Yup, I know. I would just prefer to use the infix operators as I am using a pretty massive formula and it has to be maintainable by others after I finish the project.

Comment: AND on its own does not support short circuit